# Show that U is proper subset.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $U$ a subgroup of $G$ such that the order of $U$ is a power of the prime $p$ and $U$ it's not $p$-subgroup Sylow of $G$. Show that $U$ is a proper subset of $N_G(U)$ (the normalizer of $U$).

I know that for to prove this result it's sufficient find $x\in G-U$ such that $xUx^{-1}=U$. But I don't know how find this $x$. Can you help me, please.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are correct. I somehow was thinking of the normalizer as a normal closure, and of course, the second statement is not true. Sorry again. I'll review the definitions here.

Comment: @Shoutre Don't be sorry: we all fall in those holes from time to time.

Comment: Let me give it a second try: Since $U$ is a subgroup of $G$, each element $g\in U$ is such that $gU=U=Ug$, so that $U\subseteq N_{G}(U)$. Now, $U$ is not the $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, but it certainly is contained in the $p$-Sylow subgroup, say $T$. So, I'd guess (not complete yet) that if we take an element $x\in T$ such that $x\in T-U$, it would then suffice to show that $xU=Ux$, but why this is true? Hmm

Comment: Did you mean $\;g\in G\;$ ? But then if for any such element we have $\;gU=Ug\;$ then $\; U\lhd G\;$ , which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: I was arguing to show that $U\subseteq N_{G}(U)$, so I took $g\in U$. Is this correct? I'm not yet professional mathematician and am still learning groups. Answering here is like doing exercises, so I gently ask you to be patient with my possible mistakes. xD thanks.

Comment: @Shoutre It is trivial that $\;X\le N_G(X)\;$ for any subgroup of $\;G\;$ , since it is closed under multiplication so $\;x^{-1}Xx\subset X\;$ **always**

Comment: Then it looks like I was trying to justify the obvious. The problem then was to find an element in the normalizer which is not in $U$, and my attempt was to search for such an element in the $p$-Sylow subgroup, but not in $U$. I'm still reading your answer but not sure if I understand it completely. Groups actions aren't completely natural yet, I have to read it with a book in hands.

Comment: @Shoutre It shall come in time. Actions of groups is one of the nicest, most important and useful features in group theory. Any introductory course (in any decent university) includes it, and you can find it in any decent book on this sibject.

Answer (score 2):

It is true always and in any case that $\;H\le N_G(H)\;$ , for *any* subgroup $\;H\le G\;$ , now:

(1) Proof with nilpotent groups: since $\;U\;$ is a $\;p\,-$ subgroup which is **not** a Sylow $\;p\,-$ subgroup, $\;U\;$ is properly contained in some Sylow $\;p\,-$ subgroup $\;P\le G\;$ , and $\;P\;$ is a nilpotent group as it is a finite $\;p\,-\;$ subgroup, so any proper subgroup fulfills the [Normalizer Condition](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_satisfying_normalizer_condition) , which means precisely $\;U\lneq N_P(U)\le N_G(U)\;$

(2) Proof with action of group: let $\;P\;$ be as above a Sylow subgroup, and denote by $\;X\;$ the set of left cosets of $\;U\;$ in $\;P\;$. Observe that $\;|X|\;$ is a power of $\;p\;$ since it divides $\;|P|\;$. Define an action by left shift on $\;X\;$ :

$$U\times X\to X\;,\;\;u\cdot(wP)=(uw)P$$

Observe that if we take the coset $\;U\in X\;$, we get $\;u\cdot(1U)=uU=U\;$ , so

$$\mathcal Orb(U)=\{U\}\implies |\mathcal Orb(U)|=1$$

But since the disjoint union of the orbits is $\;X\;$ and this last set has a power of $\;P\;$ elements, it *must* be that there's another element in $\;X\;$ with only one element (since the size of the orbit **also** must be a power of $\;p\;$...!), and thus there exists $\;g\in P\setminus U\;$ such that0

$$\forall\,u\in U\;,\;\;\;u\cdot(gU):=(ug)U=gU\implies g^{-1}ug\in U\implies U^g\le U$$

and since everything's finite here this means $\;U^g=G\iff g\in N_P(U)\le N_G(U)\;$